# Add constraints to collectionview programatically Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints

I have two views in my Controller UIView and UICollectionView.
and I am working with swift, not storyboard. and I am adding constraints in this way

```
// Constraints for First View
FirstView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
FirstView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
FirstView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

 //Constraints fro Collection View
 collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
 collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
 collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
 collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
```

but this crash my application. Am I wrong?
Please help me how can I do that?

Comment: can you please show crash report? so that it will help us to help you.

Comment: I got my screen blank

Comment: and the Longview?

Comment: did you add collectionView and FirstView to view?

Comment: yes, I added, if I removed Collection view constraints then it works fine. but collection view covers full screen. but I want it below to the firstView.

Comment: Please provide some more information about what you are trying to achieve (how exactly do you want your UI to look like?) and the crash.

Comment: You need to show more of your code. Especially where you add the subviews to the view.

Comment: Check my post dear, it will help you  :-)

Answer (score 1):

did you forget this?

```
FirstView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```